# Change background color of all text boxes in single click function in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Can anyone help me to Change background color of **all** text boxes in **single click function** in Windows Phone 8. In a form I have more then 50 text boxes. I can code like
textbox.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);

```
textbox1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
textbox2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
textbox3.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
textbox4.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
textbox5.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

up to

```
textbox50.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

But I need an effective way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are as usual ore ways to do it. Suppose all the TextBoxes are childres of some cotainer like a StackPanel or Grid. The simplest way would be to iterate the containers Children:

```
foreach (var elem in container.Children)
{
    if (elem is TextBox)
    {
        (elem as TextBox).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); 
    }
}
```

A better way in my opionion would be using MVVM and bind the Background property to some property in your ViewModel. If you change the property to Red, all the TextBoxes will automaticaly register the change

Comment: How to use this for Ellipse control

Comment: the same way, just add a separate if for Ellipse the same way

Comment: I have done for Ellipse by adding `using System.Windows.Shapes;`